# Nanobots Algorithm

Tags: strategy

[image]

Four tiny robots or Nanobots with dimensions 1 x 2 nm are on their initial 2 by 2 state. They shall be transform to phases I , II & III subsequently for specific tasks (see figures). Each nanobots can be instructed to rotate clockwise or counter clockwise on any of its 4 corner pivot pins. All nanobots can not slide sideways, leap over or bump with other bots. For coding purposes:

1. Let A B C & D represent the 4 bots.
2. b & d refers to upper left & right corner  while
   p & q refers to lower left & right corner regardless of the bot's orientation.
3. A parenthesis "("  or  ")" means counter-clockwise or clockwise "90 deg. rotation" respectively.

   2 symbols means 180 deg. and 3 means 270 deg. rotation. (see Example below)
   [image]

Every 90 deg. rotation (clockwise or counter-clockwise) requires 1eV energy whether the bot is
positioned vertically or horizontally . The total rotated angle or amount of energy done by all nanobots must be minimized for efficient operation.

What set of instructions must be given to the nanobots from initial position to transform to
phase I, then to phase II and phase III ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

> 20eV precisely

to I:

> Ad)) Dd( Dq( Db( Cd(

to II:

> Dd( Cp) Dp) Bp) Ab( Aq)) Ap)

to III:

> Ab( Bd) Dq) Cb( Db( Db)

Comment: Error in phase III ?

Comment: @TSLF Indeed, must have blundered encoding from the visual representation in my notes. I think it's fixed now.

Comment: I got 8eV for III so this is actually 18eV minimum?

Comment: You got the first two steps in 12?

Comment: yes both phase I & II with 6.. and  possible III to I is also 6 .